# Using mouse coordinates in javascript, how to accommodate for different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pixel

I'm trying to make a very simple slideshow based on the x and y coordinates of the mouse. At the moment I am using pixels in js - so as you can see from the code, when the mouse verges over a certain point, the display is updated for each element. Is there a way I could use percentages in javascript, instead of px? So that regardless of screen width and height, the images are shown at the same point (e.g. if the mouse is 25% over the screen, change display, rather than certain number of pixels). Here is my code:

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY; 

var image1 = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
var image2 = document.getElementsByClassName('test2')[0];

// create variables for percentages of screen?

image1.style.display = "block";
image2.style.display = "none";


function init(){

    document.onmousemove = function(e){
    mouseX = e.screenX;
    mouseY = e.screenY;
    console.log(mouseX, mouseY);
        if (mouseX <= 400) {
            image1.style.display = "none";
            image2.style.display = "block";
        } 
        else if (mouseX => 800) {
            image2.style.display = "none";
            image1.style.display = "block";
        }
       //will add more of the same here
    }
}
```

Comment: get the screen width (or height or any other reference) and use its 25 %

Comment: I was thinking of this - obviously getting these is not an issue, what I'm not sure is how to implement the percentages?

Comment: mouseX < 0.25*screenwidth  assuming 25 % should do it

Comment: think i got it, completely didn't think of just getting the widths and heights then dividing, thanks @rahultyagi

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple math to get the screen sizes.

You should start with `window.innerWidth` for the with, and `window.innerHeight` for the height.

If you know that your buttons are both 50 % of the screen width, just divide the total by 2.

```
if (mouseX < window.innerWidth / 2) {
    // Do stuff for left button
} else {
    // Do stuff for right button
}
```